# What Are the New Reference Items in My .csproj File from NuGet 2.0?

Tags: msbuild, nuget, csproj

One of our underlying projects is packaged via NuGet and distributed (internally) so that other teams can consume the library - let's call it "Core." With NuGet 1.x, we got a reference in our .csproj file that looked something like this:

```
<Reference Include="Core">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
<HintPath>..\packages\Core.1.4.1.381\lib\net40\Core.dll</HintPath>
```

After upgrading to NuGet 2.0, this same reference looks like this:

```
<Reference Include="Core, Version=1.4.1.381, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
<HintPath>..\packages\Core.1.4.1.381\lib\net40\Core.dll</HintPath>
```

In the `Include` attribute, does the Version matter? I'm explicitly setting `SpecificVersion` to false. I've looked through the [MSBuild Project File Schema Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dy88c2e), but it didn't see anything regarding how this attribute is parsed.

Thanks for input on this.

-SethO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried under VS2010, 
if you specify :

```xml
<SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
```

the version under `<Reference></Reference>` is ignored.

Comment: Thanks, Nico. Were you able to find any information about what parses/consumes the Include attribute data in the Reference tag? I'm still trying to figure out why it started showing up.

Comment: You are wondering why ... ?
You could take a look at the source code on codeplex : 
http://nuget.codeplex.com
Look after NuGet assembly, (the project is called CommandLine), there are not many assemblies referencing the Microsoft.Build API...
I bet something has changed in the **AddReference** method of `NuGet.Common.MSBuildProjectSystem` class.
Have a look to the history of the corresponding file (**MSBuildProjectSystem.cs**)

Good luck :)

Comment: I do understand that the NuGet source code put it there. I am much more interested in how it is parsed and used on the receiving end. Knowing that setting `SpecificVersion` to false allows MSBuild to ignore the version in `Reference` makes my inquiry purely academic at this point. You've allayed my fears about the additional data in the `Include` attribute.